# Is there an injective homomorphism $\phi:U_{20}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{64}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is there an injective homomorphism $\phi:U_{20}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{64}$

I haven't touched those kind of problems in a while so I kind of forgot how to approach them properly.

I know that in an injective homomorphism $o(\phi(a))=o(a)$ for all $a\in U_{20}$.

From what I could tell, every element in $U_{20}$ is from order $1$,$2$ or $4$.

Comment: Could you explain what is $U_{20}?$

Comment: Multiplicative group of units (invertible elements) modulo $20$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $U_{20}\cong\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_2$.  In particular,  it isn't cyclic ($U_n$ is cyclic iff $n$ is $1,2,4, p^k$ or $2p^k$ for $p$ an odd prime.)

If the homomorphism were injective,  then $\Bbb Z_{64}$ would have a noncyclic subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The group $U_{20}$ has $4$ elements of order $4$ (represented by $3,7,13,17$) whereas the group $\mathbb Z_{64}$ has only $2$ elements of order $4$ (represented by $16,48$).